# SQL query does not work on earlier Android versions

Tags: android, sql

I have the following SQL query in my app.  It works without any issues on my Nexus 7, but crashes with a message about the column "title" not existing on earlier versions of Android.

```
SELECT feeds._id AS _id, feeds.title, feeds.description, feeds.image,
feeds.groupName, count(items._id) AS itemCount, sum(case when items.read = 0
then 1 end) as unreadCount FROM feeds LEFT JOIN items ON (items.feedId = feeds._id)
GROUP BY feeds._id ORDER BY feeds.groupName
```

Is this a known issue, or is there something wrong with my query?

Comment: We need more code to help you...The error message about "Column 'title' not existing" may help.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a complete sqlite tutorial.](http://tugrulasik.com/2011/12/21/android-not-defteri-uygulamasi/) Be carefull about your database version. Change it first for every table structure change.